# How to send parameter to Geom.histogram when using Geom.subplot_grid in Gadfly?

Tags: plot, histogram, julia, gadfly

I am trying to plot several histograms for the same data set, but with different numbers of bins. I am using Gadfly.

Suppose `x` is just an array of real values, plotting each histogram works:

```
plot(x=x, Geom.histogram(bincount=10))
plot(x=x, Geom.histogram(bincount=20))
```

But I'm trying to put all the histograms together. I've added the number of bins as another dimension to my data set:

```
x2 = vcat(hcat(10*ones(length(x)), x), hcat(20*ones(length(x)), x)
df = DataFrame(Bins=x2[:,1], X=x2[:,2])
```

Is there any way to send the number of bins (the value from the first column) to `Geom.histogram` when using `Geom.subplot_grid`? Something like this:

```
plot(df, x="X", ygroup="Bins", Geom.subplot_grid(Geom.histogram(?)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you would be better off not using subplot grid at that point, and instead just combine them with vstack or hstack.  From the docs

```
Plots can also be stacked horizontally with ``hstack`` or vertically with 
``vstack``. This allows more customization in regards to tick marks, axis 
labeling, and other plot details than is available with ``subplot_grid``.
```